# Kendo ui picker css issue

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using kendo ui dropdown list and some other pickers. I want to style the selected item background color.

I had tried .k-dropdown .k-state-selected{ background-color: red} but the color of selected item is not changing. It is set to default orange only. But the same code is working for grid and list view.

How can i able to do that.

Regards,
Sri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following CSS should work for date(time)picker and the dropdownlist:

```
.k-widget .k-state-selected,
.k-list .k-state-selected
{ 
  background: red;
}
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/efozol/5/edit

Comment: Thank you. How can do the same for datepicker and timepicker and calender items.

Comment: I have got it for calender. How to do it for timepicker and date picker

Comment: For the date part use `.k-state-selected.k-state-focused { background: red; }` for the time `.k-item.k-state-selected { background: red; }``

Answer (score 0):

KendoUI defines background not just as a `background-color: XYZ;` but using `background-image: none, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffc0cb 0px, #ffc0cb 100%);` too
So, start overwriting this definition saying `background-image: none;`

Comment: What's that webkit-linear-gradient used for

Comment: It is a CSS3 way of dynamically generating gradients. Instead of having to have an image that displays a gradient, you use this that generates it.