# How change the background colour of the kendo ui datepicker using css

Tags: css, kendo-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kendo ui picker css issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507971/kendo-ui-picker-css-issue)

I want to change the background colour of the selected state in kendo ui date picker. I have written the code like

```
    k.datepicker .k-state-selected
    {
         background-color: blue;
    }
```

but the colour is not changing. How can i do that

Regards,

sri

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
.k-calendar .k-state-selected { background: blue; }
```

instead

Comment: Hi i am not using calendar i am using date picker still it work for date picker also

Answer (score 1):

Can you use jQuery?
It's easy to handle the focus event:

```
$("#datePicker").focus(function(){$("#datePicker").css("background-color", "blue");})
```

Comment: It's just one of the approaches. I don't make to use exactly this method. Sometimes you can't or don't want to use CSS so you can do that programmatically.