# What to change on KendoUI template for different backcolor on k-listview selection?

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, backcolor

I am new working with KendoUI and need to modify the default backcolor for selected item on k-listview (currently orange), however I have not been able to find out where is it and the css is hard to read since they use no space or carrier return on file.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: It the answer was helpful - upvote it please. If it answered you question upvote + accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sample code

```
.k-calendar .k-state-selected { background: blue; }
```

from the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13560595/502950)

You shouldnt use calendar, but element you need

Comment: This was helpful, but my solution was: 

.k-listview .k-state-selected
{
    background-image: none,linear-gradient(to bottom,#D5D5D5 0,#D5D5D5 100%);
}